# I get a different answer on this separable differential equation than I'm supposed to.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential-forms

I let $y = v'$, But when I try and do it i get $v = e^x + e^{c_1} + c_2.$
Can someone please show me?
$$v'' -v' =0$$

=> $v=C_1e^x +C_2$, this is supposed to be it.

Comment: $e^{c_1}+c_2$ is a constant, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$v''-v'=0$$
$$y'-y=0$$
$$(ye^{-x})'=0$$
Integrate
$$ye^{-x}=c_1$$
$$v'=c_1e^{x}$$
Integrate again:
$$v=c_1e^x+c_2$$

---

I used integrating factor for solving this DE:
$$y'-y=0$$
But it's also separable:
$$y'=y$$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y}=1$$
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{y}=\int dx$$
$$\ln y= x+c_1$$
$$y=e^{x+c_1}$$
$$y=ce^x$$

Comment: How do you come up with this y′−y=0
             =>  (ye−x)′=0

Comment: It's the integrating factor $\mu =e^{-x}$ @user773674 You multiply both sides by the integrating factor

Comment: ohh its clear now thanks

Comment: Sure write it as $(xv')'=0$ and integrate it directly @user773674

Comment: Damn, i need some sleep thanks again

Comment: Then $xv'=c_1 \implies v'=\dfrac {c_1}x$ integrate to get the final answer @user773674

Comment: You're welcome @user773674

Answer (score 0):

As  $$e^{c_1} + c_2  = C(An \ arbitary \ constant)$$
The family of curves is $$ y = e^x + C$$
which satisfies 
$$y^{\prime} = e^x$$